# Laravel Queue PushRaw Delay?

Tags: laravel, queue, beanstalkd, laravel-4.2

I have an app wherein from laravel 4.2 I am slowly transitioning it to node.

Now I have this `Queue::pushRaw(payload, tube)` the job is in node and this code is working perfectly fine.

However I recently have a problem wherein I need those jobs to have a delay.

I use `Queue::later` before (when my jobs is still in Laravel), but how can I do it with `Queue::pushRaw` ?? I can't use `Queue::later` anymore since I'm passing a raw payload instead of a job.

Base on the documents I can pass `options` 
https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Queue/QueueInterface.html

However, I have no idea what to pass on `options` to have a delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I discovered this file: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Queue/BeanstalkdQueue.php#L66 (I'm using Beanstald)

You can't really pass a delay since DEFAULT_DELAY is 0.

So my solution is to create a job in Laravel.

I can then do `Queue::later(delay, myJobThatCallsThePushRaw, data, queue);`

and then on `myJobThatCallsThePushRaw` I do `Queue::pushRaw(my-node-payload)` inside.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I did this delay in my code, I added a field in database, before I do my job, I check last time of check.If past X second, OK you can do this job, other side requeue with delay.

in the consumer of my queue:

```
 RabbitmqFacade::consumer('trx_need_to_confirm_check', function ($data) {
                $message = json_decode($data->body, true);


                if ($message['type'] == 1) {
                    $operationResult = $this->tronMainConfirmService->startService($message);
                }
                else {
                    $operationResult = $this->tronMainWithdrawalService->startCheckConfirmService($message);
                }

                if (!$operationResult['ackAble']) {
                    RabbitmqFacade::product('trx_need_to_confirm_check', $message, true, true, 30000);
                }
                $data->ack();
            });
```